# WordPress - Custom Product Search Option in Home Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system

I've a `WordPress` website and am trying to add a custom search option in the website's home page as well in the header section. Unfortunately I can't see any option to include it from the website's dashboard and decided to follow the link to create a custom one as follows:

[Tutorial Link - Custom Search](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-search-bar-headerfooter) 

and this is the code that I've tried same as the tutorial:

```
add_action('tickercontainer','add_search_to_footer'); //Guessinghere I've to declare the div class

function add_search_to_footer() {
get_search_form();
}

function SearchFilter($query) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post'); //OR USE 'PRODUCT'
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

function storefront_search_form_modify( $html ) {
    return str_replace( array('Search &hellip;','Search'), array('WooCommerce Hooks, Storefront Theme, Google AdWords...','Search Article'), $html );
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'storefront_search_form_modify' );

function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    $searchicon = '<li class="search"><a href="#colophon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>';
    $items = $items . $searchicon;
    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_additional-resources_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Though I am not sure what I am missing here and would expect some ideas to implement in an appropriate way.

**Note**: Right now, after including the code above, I can't see the search option in the website.

Comment: I believe, @LoicTheAztec - The expert can help here.